# How add decoration arrow for pgfplotfunction

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a series of curves with directions. `pgfplotfunction` is an option because it's easy to draw curves in a batch.

However, I don't know how to add annotation arrow for it. It's there a similar way for pgf as the `decorations` library for `\draw`?

Sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[clip] (-1,-1)--(1,-1)--(1,1)--(-1,1)--cycle;
\draw (-1,0) -- (1,0);
\draw (0,-1) -- (0,1);
\begin{scope}[rotate=60]
\foreach \s in {1,2,3,4,5,6} {
    \pgfplothandlerlineto
        \pgfplotfunction{\t}{0,10,...,1024}{\pgfpointxy{(0.0005+0.0001*\s)*\t*2*cos(\t)}{(0.0005+0.0001*\s)*\t*sin(\t)}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You know that this is also possible in TikZ notation with much simpler syntax?

Comment: @percusse, I know `\draw plot[parametric id=xxx] function` can be used to draw a curve, however, it doesn't work well in a batch, because it relies on external tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand what you mean by external tool or not working in batch but here is a TikZ version of the same problem for comparison with some annotation (though you didn't specify the annotation spec.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[clip] (-1,-1)--(1,-1)--(1,1)--(-1,1)--cycle;
\draw (-1,0) -- (1,0);
\draw (0,-1) -- (0,1);
\begin{scope}[rotate=60]
\foreach \s in {1,2,3,4,5,6} {
    \pgfplothandlerlineto
        \pgfplotfunction{\t}{0,10,...,1024}{\pgfpointxy{(0.0005+0.0001*\s)*\t*2*cos(\t)}{(0.0005+0.0001*\s)*\t*sin(\t)}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.3 with {\arrow{stealth}}}]
\begin{scope}% Limit the clip effect
  \draw[clip] (-1,-1)--(1,-1)--(1,1)--(-1,1)--cycle;
  \draw (-1,0) -- (1,0);
  \draw (0,-1) -- (0,1);
  \begin{scope}[rotate=60]
    \foreach \s in {1,...,6}{
      \draw[postaction={decorate}] plot[domain=0:1024,samples=102,variable=\t] 
      ({(0.0005+0.0001*\s)*\t*2*cos(\t)},{(0.0005+0.0001*\s)*\t*sin(\t)});
    }
  \end{scope}
\end{scope}
\draw[->,blue,ultra thick] (1,1)node{Annotate}-- (0.2,0.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's exactly what I wanted. I just don't know the correct syntax in tikz way.